# How to improve the features from a convnnet for image retrieval?

Tags: neural-network, keras, conv-neural-network, resnet

I have 3 classes. (50k for training, 12k for validation)
By using pretrained vgg16 and resnet50, and freezing the models and only training a dense layer on top, I reach a validation accuracy of 99%. 
Should I fine tune to improve features by unfreezing the layers or should I use the features as it is?
Also, is vgg16 a better feature extractor than Resnet50 or should I use features from Resnet?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your problem domain. If you are fine-tuning the pretrained model for the same problem domain and the training data size is small, then what you have done is correct.

Maybe if you freeze only the first layers, which are well trained on for general feature extraction (egdes, blobs, shapes ..etc), you can boost your performance. It also recommended to apply data augmentation if you are going to do this to avoid over fitting

I encourage you to check the following tutorial on Transfer Learning for more details:
http://cs231n.github.io/transfer-learning/